# Keystone with Material Design Bootstrap Incompatible units: 'rem' and 'px'

Tags: node.js, material-design, bootstrap-4, keystone

Did anyone managed to add the SCSS from [Material Design Bootstrap](https://mdbootstrap.com/) in the default template of [Keystone.js](http://keystonejs.com/) ?

I am new to node.js and front-end development so I am not sure what I am doing but, I bascially added the `MDB` folder in my `public/styles`. After that I've modified the `sites.scss`, I commented out `@import "site/variables";` and `@import "site/layout";` and I added `@import "mdb";` but this does not really seemed to work. I get the error:

```
in /my_path/public/styles/mdb/free/data/_variables-b4.scss:320:34
Error thrown for request: /styles/site.css
Error: Incompatible units: 'rem' and 'px'.
    at options.error (/my_path/node_modules/node-sass/lib/index.js:291:26)
```

Anyone any idea?

Comment: What's your version of MDB? Do you use free or pro version?

Comment: Hey! I am using 4.3.2, the free version. @Mattonit

Comment: I have this issue too!  Ever find a solution?